# Two ways for accessing android string resources

Tags: android, performance, resources

I'm trying to figure out the difference between accessing android string **resources**. The following quote is not clear to me:

> Access by referene is fast
>
> Direct access is slow

**access by reference** means: `setTitle(R.string.title)`

**direct access** means: `setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title))`

Now I've run some speed tests on the android emulator:

**access by reference**:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 100000; i++) {
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
```

This took **5090 milliseconds**. In contrast I run the same code, using **direct access**:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 100000; i++) {
    setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
}
```

This took **5191 milliseconds**. I tested this with Android 4.2.2.

So for me it looks a lot like it doesn't matter which way I use the resources. **Did this matter in earlier android versions? Does this matter on real devices? In other words: Does it matter which access I choose?**

If more parameters of my testing are needed, I'm happy to give them. Thank you for taking the time, appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the code :

(in Activity)

```
public void setTitle(int titleId) {
    setTitle(getText(titleId));
}
```

(in Context)

```
public final CharSequence getText(int resId) {
    return getResources().getText(resId);
}
```

So basically, it is exactly the same thing.

What is much slower, however, is if you use `Resource.getIdentifier(String, String, String)` to find the ids of your resources.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to the specific implementation. It really boils down to the identical calls.